# Qt AutoConnect actions

Tags: c++, qt

i have created a form using qt designer and created an QAction  with objectName `actionEmployeeWin` and i wanted to use autoconnect feature of qt, but its isn't working

**main_win.cpp**

```
#include "main_win.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "employe_win.h"

#include <QSettings>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    empWin(nullptr), providerWin(nullptr)

{
    // setting up ui and loading last geometry
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSettings settings;
    restoreGeometry(settings.value("MAINWINDOW/GEOMETRY").toByteArray());
    restoreState(settings.value("MAINWINDOW/WINSTATE").toByteArray());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *evt) {
    QSettings appSetting;

    appSetting.setValue("MAINWINDOW/GEOMETRY", saveGeometry());
    appSetting.setValue("MAINWINDOW/WINSTATE", saveState());
    QMainWindow::closeEvent(evt);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionEmployeeWin_triggered(bool checked)
{
    std::cout << "working"; // do not show
}
```

*main_win.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "employe_win.h"
#include "provider_win.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *evt);

    void on_actionEmployeeWin_triggered(bool checked);

private:
    void createMenu();

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    EmployeeWindow *empWin;
    ProviderWindow *providerWin;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *inherit* from the Ui form in order to be able to use the automatic connection feature.

See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtuitools-multipleinheritance-example.html

Note: I usually *don't* recommend to rely on the automatic connection feature, just because of issues like this. Automatic connections are non-explicit and problems with them are difficult to debug. Too much `QMetaObject` magic for my taste.